# Implementation of Varnish's `vcl_hash`

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

<s>It's my understanding that varnish's `vcl` configuration files are just C files</s>.  It's my new understanding that varnish's VCL files are a domain specific language that shares many similarities with C. However, I'm not familiar with modern C, and pretty rusty with my cave-man college C, and I don't understand how varnish's `vcl_hash` function works.

Specifically, a typical `vcl_hash` function will look like this.

```
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (hash);
}
```

The `hash_data` function calls seem pretty straight forward -- I assume its adding the desired information to consider for the cache-key into a data structure of some kind.

What's confusing me is the final call

```
return (hash);
```

What is `vcl_hash` returning here?  What is `(hash)`?  Is it a function? If so, how is C calling it without parenthesis (`hash()`) -- or is varnish doing something clever behind the scenes?

Comment: "vcl configuration files are just C files"... nope. ["You write VCL code which Varnish will parse, **translate to C code**, compile and link to."](https://www.varnish-software.com/book/3/VCL_Basics.html)

Comment: `sub` is a C keyword? New standard?

Comment: Thanks both, question clarified to remove erroneous assumptions.

Comment: @Olaf `sub` is not a C keyword, it's just a varnish keyword to define functions.

Comment: @Redithion: No kidding! I really was searching for C15 standard. ;-) - disclaimer: If you find sarcasm, please be nice to it and give it a good home. Feed with trolls.

Comment: @Olaf the fact that my sarcasm detector is not working does not allow you to be unkind! lol

Answer (score 1):

The return statements in VCL actually refer to "actions". It effectively  forces Varnish to go into the next phase of the request processing. Returning nothing will It actually seems strange to `return (hash)` from `vcl_hash` itself, as generally you would do that from vcl_recv to tell it to kick into the object lookup phase.

Normally vcl_hash would `return (lookup)` or nothing at all (to complete with the "built-in" vcl_hash, which applies hostname and url). "lookup" will short-circuit any additional vcl_hash implementations that might exist and go straight into the lookup phase.

Answer (score 0):

Hash is a Varnish variable, from the [varnish documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#variables):

> The hash key used to refer to an object in the cache. Used when both
>   reading from and writing to the cache.

Have in mind that you can find hash as req.hash (req.hash is for Varnish versions older than 3.0)

hash_data works as you said, more specifically (again, from [varnish documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#functions)):

> hash_data(str)
>
> Adds a string to the hash input. In default.vcl hash_data() is called on the host and URL of the request.